# Prove formally that $v_n(t)\to v(t)$ uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $t\in (0, 2)$ and let $v_n(t) = \sqrt{(t-1)^2+1/n}$. I am pretty sure that $v_n(t)\to v(t)$ uniformly, with $v(t) = |t-1|$.

Could someone please help me in proving this formally?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Domain of t defined?

Comment: @herbsteinberg $t\in (0, 2)$, I edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the monotonicity and the subadditivity of the square root you have that $$ \vert t-1 \vert \leq v_n(t)\leq \vert t-1\vert+\frac{1}{n}$$;
consequently
$$ \left\| v_n(t) - \vert t-1 \vert \,  \right\| \leq \frac{1}{n}, $$
and you conclude because the estimate does not depend by $t.$